# conditional change of a datagridviews cell background color and text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, colors, cell

This is for a winform vb.net 2008 app.  I'm bringing data back from a database and based on some static conditions... i want to change the color of the background and the text.  There is no rowdatabound event in winform...

hope someone can provide some guidance
thanks
shannon

Comment: I can think of at least 20 different ways to bring data back from a DB so it could be helpful if you were a little more specific.

Comment: sorry about that... i'm not having trouble bringing data back from the db, it's formatting the style of the cell that the data is going into.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working... in the `RowPostPaint` event.. If I put in

```
if (my criteria here)
    Me.dgTableInfo.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ColumnName").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set the selectoinBackColor too... otherwise if your red row changes, but you have it highlighted, it will look just like all the rest anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This works without creating or calling multiple subs or functions. Seems to work for every instance I need it to.

```
Do While myDataReader.Read()
    ItemID = Trim(myDataReader.Item("ITEM").ToString())
    PAR = myDataReader.Item("PAR").ToString()
    Returned = myDataReader.Item("RETURNED_AMOUNT")
    Taken = myDataReader.Item("TAKEN_AMOUNT")
    OnHand = ((PAR + Returned) - Taken)

    DataGridViewItemList.Rows.Add(ItemID, PAR, Returned, Taken, OnHand)

    RI = DataGridViewItemList.Rows.Count - 1
    If OnHand <= (PAR / 2) Then
        DataGridViewItemList.Rows(RI).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkSalmon
    Else
        DataGridViewItemList.Rows(RI).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Nothing
    End If
Loop
```