# WPF datagrid - custom colors for each cell

Tags: wpf, user-interface, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

In my application, I build all the rows and columns for a DataGrid programmatically. I would now like to control different UI aspects such as color, font, font size, borders, etc. programmatically for each cell. I am wondering if there is any on-cell-paint event that I can add a callback to and set all the aspects on per-cell basis. An example would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you aware of the WPF templating system? I'd consider using templates to achieve this - I'm pretty sure it will cover cell level styling in a datagrid (I may be wrong though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found was to capture OnLoadingRow() of DataGrid. The following link shows a working example:

[How to set background of a datagrid cell during AutoGeneratingColumn event depending on its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645688/how-to-set-background-of-a-datagrid-cell-during-autogeneratingcolumn-event-depen)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not. I had the same problem as you and my solution was to create my own custom column and override the GenerateElement. I'll show you the code i can:

```
<cdgc:ColorTextColumn Binding="{Binding value}"
```

And then:

```
protected override System.Windows.FrameworkElement GenerateElement(System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var text = new TextBlock();
        text.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        text.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, this.CopyBinding(this.DataBinding, null, null, null));

        text.Foreground = (System.Windows.Media.Brush).....;

        return text;
    }
```

As you can see I set the binding previously and maintained in the cell generation