# Change datagridview cell background based on a external parameter

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datagridview, cell

I should change the color to a cell which contains the parameter 'tarjeta_fam'. I tried to change the cell default property and then invalidate the row to refresh it, but (obviously) nothing happens. It's possible to change a cell color out of the cell formatting event?

```
Public Sub New(user As Usuario, ByVal tarjeta_fam As String)
  InitializeComponent()

  gridFamiliares.DataSource = BD.getTable(a query)

  If Me.gridFamiliares.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.gridFamiliares.Rows.Count - 1
      If Me.gridFamiliares.Rows(i).Cells("tarjeta_fam").Value = tarjeta_fam Then
         Me.gridFamiliares.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black
         Me.gridFamiliares.InvalidateRow(i)
      End If
    Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing datagridview cell color based on condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380279/changing-datagridview-cell-color-based-on-condition)

Comment: possible duplicate of [conditional change of a datagridviews cell background color and text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639639/conditional-change-of-a-datagridviews-cell-background-color-and-text) ... or choose from many other on the right under "RELATED"

Comment: indicated as duplicate: change this: `Me.gridFamiliares.Rows(i).Cells(index).Value.tostring = "tarjeta_fam "Then`

Comment: the question isn't duplicated, i'm asking if it is possible to change the color receiving an external variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGridView control really wants you to use the CellFormatting event for this, so declare a form level variable to be used by that event:

```
Private tarjeta_fam_Value As String = String.Empty

Public Sub New(user As Usuario, ByVal tarjeta_fam As String)
  InitializeComponent()
  gridFamiliares.DataSource = BD.getTable(a query)
  tarjeta_fam_Value = tarjeta_fam
End Sub

Private Sub gridFamiliares_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles gridFamiliares.CellFormatting
  If tarjeta_fam_Value <> String.Empty Then
    With gridFamiliares.Rows(e.RowIndex)
      If .Cells("tarjeta_fam").Value = tarjeta_fam_Value Then
        .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black
      End If
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```